# vaadin label not showing although the textbox appears fine

Tags: vaadin

This is the constructor of the class I wrote, the textbox is showing but the label not:-

```
    public StartingTest(String op) {
    this.op = op;
    setStyleName("mainpanel");
    setCaption("Bonus Row");
    row = new GridLayout(2, 1);

    lblSource.setCaption("Source Profile: ");
    lblSource.setSizeUndefined();
    row.addComponent(lblSource, 0, 0);
    row.addComponent(txtSourceProfile, 1, 0);
    this.addComponent(row);
}
```

Comment: Did the answer help you? Please give feedback, e.g. mark it as answer of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your label's size is undefined. That means that your label's width is only as wide as it has to be to show the label's **value**. Your label's value is empty so you don't see your label. A fix would be to use `setValue()` instead of `setCaption()`. Also you could remove `setSizeUndefined()` and use the default label width of 100%.